# Google thinks I am a robot when using proxy, but only in Safari

Tags: proxy, google, safari

Google greeted me with this message while being behind a private proxy:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.
>   This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and
>   not a robot.

I did my research and is seems that this is caused by automated searching, which I am not doing. I guessed that someone was doing automated search with the proxy I have (private proxy ehhh?). Now comes the part I don't understand and it differs from other questions: This only happens while using Safari and does not when using Chrome. Why is that? Did the automated searcher used Safari's User-Agent? I thought that google bans everyone using the same IP as the bot, which is unpleasant when using mobile bandwidth.

Comment: I agree this is a bit odd, but I suspect only Google knows the internal workings of their bot detection. So all one can do here is to speculate.

Answer (score 3):

Google's [new reCAPTCHA uses cookies](https://www.funcaptcha.com/2015/01/06/recaptcha-is-still-vulnerable-perhaps-even-more-than-ever-before/):

> To put it simply: user’s past behavior and previous CAPTCHA solves are recorded in their cookies, which are then detected by future reCAPTCHA challenges.

So seeing different behavior in different browsers isn't surprising. You may find that using an incognito/private browser window changes the behavior.

Comment: I deleted all cookies from all browsers. Same behaviour. Ended up switching proxies.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you will commonly face through TOR too.

Since a large number of people may be using the same server/exit-node as a proxy, Google receives a larger number of requests from a single machine. When it detects this, it asks you to solve a captcha to prove that you aren't a robot.

It doesn't matter if your using safari. Use chrome, and you will eventually receive the message too.